# Integral of Product of Two Gaussian Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have Two Independent Gaussian Random Variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ both with zero mean and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively.  I want to characterize the distribution of the following:
$$Z = \int_{0}^{T}X_1(t-\tau)X_2(t)dt$$

I am pretty confident that the mean of $Z$ is zero but I am not sure how to characterize it further.  I know that the product of two Gaussians look like the superposition of two Chi Squared random variables.  Will the output $Z$ look Gaussian by some type of CLT argument (T can be large if needed)?  Any help or advice on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hm, I see a downvote but no comment or answer. Please help me: what should I be thinking now?

Comment: I'm not sure the reason for the downvote :( I any pretty stuck on this problem.  Characterizing the variance of $Z$ seems non-trivial to me and I am not sure the underlying distribution of $Z$

Comment: By $X_1(t-\tau)X_2(t)dt$ do you mean $f_{X_1}(t-\tau)f_{X_2}(t)dt$?

Comment: I would like to try to help, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm assuming that by $Z$, $X_1$, and $X_2$, you're referring to the probability distributions of those random variables.  In which case, since $X_1(t-\tau)=X_1(\tau-t)$, you're looking at a convolution of two Gaussians (or would be if the limits of integration were $\pm \infty$), which is itself a Gaussian.